# Windows 7 homegroup sharing problem

Tags: windows-7

I have two machines in a homegroup. My desktop and my wife's laptop. The public folders like pictures, videos, etc. are shared fine. But if I try to share a single folder with the homegroup from the laptop, I don't see it on my desktop.

I see suggestions of rebooting, leaving and rejoining the homegroup; even recreating the homegroup. Frankly, that's just ridiculous. If those are the only solutions then the feature is just not working as it should.

Is it possible I'm experiencing these problems because I am still running the public beta of WIndows 7 (yeah I know, I need to get over my laziness and reinstall) while my wife is running the release version? Are there solutions to this problem that don't involve the somewhat drastic measures mentioned above?

Comment: I just found that password protected sharing was turned on, on the laptop. I've turned it off but still don't see the folder under the machine in the homegroup.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is beta related.

Basically, if it is was a standard feature that was in every version of Windows, it is fine to help you, but you can't really begin to diagnose a problem like this on a brand new feature if you are not using the final release as they most certainly would of made changes to it.

Comment: @Steve Crane: Much agreed - Homegroup is problematic enough on Win7 release. The beta version just adds more unforeseen headaches.